# handing daily tasks in rails with timezones and DST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone, dst

In my app, users can select a time that they want to receive a daily email. I then regularly run a script to find users who have an upcoming email to send and send it. So, if users elect to have an email that goes out at 7AM, I look for users with that selected as their time and send it.

The problem is of course timezones. I'm going to have users in different timezones and need 7AM to always be 7AM, regardless of timezones or daylight savings.

I can understand how to do it for display purposes, but I can't find much info on executing queries that have to factor in the timezone and DST for a collection of users with varying times and timezones.

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be most easily accomplished by simply saving everything in the database as UTC. You can adjust the times for display and incoming form data by using the users' specified time zone.

Comment: sure, but in the script that searches all users to determine who to send out the email for, how would i handle differing timezones and DST rules so that 7AM is always 7AM for a given user, and never 6AM or 8AM all of a sudden.

Comment: http://alwayscoding.ca/momentos/2013/08/22/handling-dates-and-timezones-in-ruby-and-rails/

Comment: neither of those discuss how to handle DST and timezones in queries

Comment: You can't do it in the query unless you keep offset data in the database too. Otherwise you just have to grab everything and compute it on the fly